# C struct or pointer to struct?

Tags: c, beginner, matrix, pointers

I am currently using this code (and more) to deal with 2D matrices. I am not very proficient in C, so I am not quite sure, if this is a good way of doing it.
I've seen other people in similar situations using pointers to a struct, but I didn't want to complicate things...

```
typedef struct CMatrix {
    double *m;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
} CMatrix;
```

-

```
CMatrix newCMatrix(uint32_t width, uint32_t height) {
    CMatrix rtn;
    rtn.m = malloc(width * height * sizeof(double));
    bzero(rtn.m, width * height * sizeof(double));

    rtn.width = width;
    rtn.height = height;

    return rtn;
}
```

-

```
CMatrix ma = newCMatrix(2, 2);
```

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: What is the use of this `bzero` ?

Comment: because the memory returned by malloc() is not initialized, I'm setting it to all zeros.

Comment: Use `memset` instead of `bzero`. But it is better to use `calloc` than using `malloc` + `memset`

Comment: You are not using signed integers to represent sizes/indices (Well done), but note that the standard library provide an specific type for this purpose: `size_t`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers seem more complicated, but they're usually faster and more correct.

### Faster

For example, perhaps you have a function like this:

```
CMatrix add(CMatrix left, CMatrix right)
{
     ... add the matrices ...
}
```

In the above you're passing matrix parameters by value instead of by pointer. That means that you're passing a copy of each matrix (instead of a pointer to each matrix).

Assuming you have 32-bit pointers, each matrix is 12 bytes in size (4 bytes for the pointer and 4 bytes for each integer), so you're passing 24 bytes (for two matrices) instead of 8 bytes (for two pointers-to-matrices).

That (24 bytes instead of 8 bytes) is not a big difference (i.e. not much slower); but it's a bigger difference when your structs are larger and more complicated.

### More correct

Another problem is that subroutines are operating on a private, local copy of the matrix; for example:

```
void transpose(CMatrix matrix)
{
    ... height becomes width and vice versa ...
    uint32_t oldWidth = matrix.width;
    uint32_t oldHeight = matrix.height;
    matrix.width = oldHeight;
    matrix.height = oldWidth;
    ... and transpose the data ...
}
```

This function changes the width and height of its local copy of the matrix, not the width and height of the caller's copy of the matrix.

### Summary

Your code happens to work because:

- You have a simple structure
- You don't alter height and width in a subroutine, after you create the matrix
- The data itself within the matrix (i.e. the `double *m` pointer) is a pointer (and is therefore shared between subroutines)

However it's bad practice: if you're coding in C, you should become familiar with using pointers.

There's nothing wrong with the `newCMatrix` function you showed in the OP. What I'm criticizing is your statement that pointers complicate things, because they're usually necessary, e.g. for other functions; for example, the 'add' function above should (in order to be idiomatic) be declared more like the following:

```
CMatrix add(const CMatrix *left, const CMatrix *right)
{
     ... add the matrices ...
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `transpose(const CMatrix)` would return the result in a new `CMatrix`. The caller would have to remember to free a lot of stuff, which could get tricky.

Comment: Yes, transpose would have to return a new CMatrix if it couldn't alter the existing one: `CMatrix transposed = transpose(matrix);`. Perhaps pass-by-value works well for the OP, given the peculiar nature of the CMatrix struct (i.e. logically const height and width properties, with the mutable data located in a pointer-type member); I hoped to warn that C code doesn't always/generally work correctly without using pointers, and that pointers are idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about the whole call by value / call by reference issue, because so far I didn't have any functions that manipulate the matrices...

Answer (score 1):

*This answer replaces poor advice in a previous answer.*

You can use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` and `bzero()`.

Your `newCMatrix()` is otherwise fine.  If you write a `newCMatrix(uint32_t, uint32_t)`, though, you should also provide a corresponding `freeCMatrix(CMatrix)` to deallocate the array.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have a freeCMatrix() function, but I didn't include it in this post.